# Swift5 how to format dateTime String in a different format

Tags: swift5, dateformatter

I m using swift5 to build my ios App. So with the follow code I write on my View the date time. The type of order.dateTime is String

```
cell.lbl_Date.text = "DATA : \(order.dateTime)"
```

The result on View is this:

```
DATA: 2021-09-09 22:11:40
```

I need to have this data:

```
DATA: 09/09/2012 22:11
```

What can I do to format the date?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the date format that you want with code like this, which you can also try running in a Swift Playground:

```swift
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
print(df.string(from: Date()))
```

You can use other format strings as well to get different date formats as needed.